# How to delete all specific elements in array in swift?

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, xcode6, filtering

I have an array that contains: [blah blah, [Read More], blah2 blah2, [Read More], blah3 blah3, [Read More], ...... this continues for another 47 times.

How can I delete/filter all the elements that are [Read More]

Thanks

Comment: are these strings or arrays or what exactly? you would be looping through to look for occurrences

Answer (score 1):

I worked it. This does work.

let summaryArrayText2 = summaryArrayText.filter( {$0 != "[Read More]"})